# Ways to deploy custom iPhone application? Outside the US

Tags: ios, iphone, deployment

we run a small software company in Guatemala and we're having a bad time deciding/investigating how to deploy an app we were hired to develop.

The current options are, enrolling on the enterprise program, but does that means that we are as a third party cannot do that? How do we get the DUN for our client? (we would jump the app store validation)

Enroll to the traditional developer program and have our application sold via the B2B portal, but Guatemala is not listed as a country where our customer can enroll (and as a custom app we dont know if the approval process would approve our app)

Please any previous experience you can share is welcome.

Comment: Short answer to your question, you need to have developer account, to create provisioning profile having device UDID attached. In your case, you can request your client to create developer account or enterprise account for you or request his client to create developer or enterprise account. Hope this info helps you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with below steps:

1) Create developer account on Apple. (You may ask to client to create it).

2) Request client to provide devices UDID number on which, they will test your app. (You can achieve this by going to iTunes, once device connected).

3) Create AppID, provisional profile with client UDID added.

4) Create AdHoc bundle and sent to client for testing the app.

5) Just check the AppStore from where your client can download app from app store. And simple upload the app on AppStore and check that country only.

Note:
To deploy app on App Store, you need developer account. You can not deploy app on App Store with Enterprice account.

Hope, you got an idea of whole process.

Let me know in case of any difficulty.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As stated above in comment. You need to have developer account, to create provisioning profile having device UDID attached.

In your case, you can request your client to create developer account or enterprise account for you or request his client to create developer or enterprise account.

You can also use [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/) which is great tool for sharing enterprise applications for iOS.

Hope this info helps you.